# How to validate a choice field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

Hi all I have a choice field in a list which has data as below

```
Select
UK
USA
France
```

**Select** is just a value I place there to show users so that they have to select an item from the list.

How do I validate a users so that they don't save without selecting either **uk,usa or france** .

I am not using a infopath.

Comment: You can add column validation that choice column value can not be 'Select'.  This will help !

Comment: how will i add it ? can you show me sample formula ? . is it something to be done in javascript ?

Comment: Its out the box part. You don't need javascript. Follow steps in answer

Comment: Do you want a JavaScript code for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to edit choice column for which you need to have validation.Go to Column validation
Add below formula

```
=ChoiceColumnName<>"Select"
```

Here 'ChoiceColumnName' is name of your column and 'Select' is you value which you don't want user to save.
Add your custom message and save.

Hope this helps !!